# Cython: redirect output to file of C function to Python string

Tags: python, string, file-io, cython

I have a C function that writes output to a file (`.pxd` file definition follows):

```
int write_prob(ProbObj* problem, const char* fname)
```

(This writes a human-readable formulation of `problem` to a file named `fname`.) I would like to use this function from Python, but with output redirected to a Python string. I have looked at the tempfile module, but do not really know how to approach the problem.

I do know how to wrap the function in a `.pyx` file, just not how to do the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

There's no other simple way I see than to make a tempoary file (`tempfile.mkstemp()`), pass the result to `write_prob` and `read` that file back into a string.

It could work in theory to implement a "virtual" file-system to redirect IO calls.  It does sound overboard, though.